# Upgrading to Rspec rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

Trying to upgrade from 2.14.2,to rspec 3.x get deprication messages

```
The `:example_group` key in an example group's metadata hash is deprecated. Use the example group's hash directly for the computed keys and `:parent_example_group` to access the parent example group metadata instead. Called from /home/georgi/ruby/xxx/spec/models/user_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'.
```

This message is showed for every line in spec file that have 'describe'. Gems that i use in test env is

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.42.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'rspec-retry'
  gem 'simplecov'
end
```

Information from config.raise_errors_for_deprecations! configuration:

https://gist.github.com/tapalilov/b96b4e2f4237e2ecef84

How to remove these deprecation messages and how to change rspec configuration?

Best regards,
Georgi.

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest versions of those gems - some have been updated for rspec 3. Some non testing gems (eg draper) also need to be updated for rspec 3

Comment: in this spec i only use 'shoulda matchers' matchers. Maybe problem is from this gem

Comment: It doesn't even have to be something that that spec uses - merely loading a gem can cause that deprecation warning

Comment: i found it which gem is cause this deprecation warning. its when require 'pundit/rspec'. i`ve required them one by one.

Comment: when visit https://github.com/elabs/pundit/issues their issues page are full with deprecation warning issues. Thank you @FrederickCheung for point me right direction